Created cesium wall can be seen through the surface(terrain)
First of all, I cut the earth by primitives so that it only shows specific local terrain then I create a underground entity wall around the specific area. But the wall can been seen through the terrain.I have tried set globe.translucency.enabled = false, but not work.
Here is the code
description gif
description image
initCesium()
renderGEOLayer([]) // [] is Latitude and longitude point formatted from GeoJSON
renderWall([])
// init
const initCesium = () => {
  cesiumViewer.value = new Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    animation: false, //动画小部件
    baseLayerPicker: false, //地图图层组件
    fullscreenButton: false, //全屏组件
    geocoder: false, //地理编码搜索组件
    homeButton: false, //首页组件
    infoBox: false, //信息框
    sceneModePicker: false, //场景模式
    selectionIndicator: false, //选取指示器组件
    timeline: false, //时间轴
    navigationHelpButton: false, //帮助按钮
    navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible: false,
    skyAtmosphere: false,
    // 加载默认地形数据
    terrain: Cesium.Terrain.fromWorldTerrain(),
    contextOptions: {
      webgl: {
        alpha: true
      }
    }
  });
  cesiumViewer.value.scene.backgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
  cesiumViewer.value.scene.globe.translucency.enabled = false;
}
// add Instance
const addRect = (
  instances: Cesium.GeometryInstance[],
  left: number,
  down: number,
  right: number,
  up: number
) => {
  instances.push(
    new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
      geometry: new Cesium.RectangleGeometry({
        rectangle: Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(left, down, right, up)
      }),
      attributes: {
        color: Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(
          Cesium.Color.fromCssColorString(InstanceColor)
        )
      }
    })
  );
};

// let cesium global only display specific area
const renderGEOLayer = (pointsArray: number[]) => {
  if (!cesiumViewer.value) return;
  let polygonWithHole = new Cesium.PolygonGeometry({
    polygonHierarchy: new Cesium.PolygonHierarchy(
      Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([73.0, 53.0, 73.0, 0.0, 135.0, 0.0, 135.0, 53.0]),
      [new Cesium.PolygonHierarchy(Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(pointsArray))]
    )
  });
  let geometry = Cesium.PolygonGeometry.createGeometry(polygonWithHole);
  let instances: Cesium.GeometryInstance[] = [];
  geometry &&
    instances.push(
      new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
        geometry: geometry,
        attributes: {
          color: Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(
            Cesium.Color.fromCssColorString(InstanceColor)
          )
        }
      })
    );
  addRect(instances, -180.0, -90.0, 73.0, 90.0);
  addRect(instances, 135.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0);
  addRect(instances, 73.0, 53.0, 135.0, 90.0);
  addRect(instances, 73.0, -90.0, 135.0, 0.0);
  cesiumViewer.value.scene.primitives.add(
    new Cesium.Primitive({
      geometryInstances: instances,
      appearance: new Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance({
        flat: true,
        translucent: false
      }),
      asynchronous: false
    })
  );
};
// add wall
const renderWall = (pointsArray: number[]) => {
  if (!cesiumViewer.value) return;
  // max height: 0
  // let maximumHeights = new Array(pointsArray.length / 2).fill(0);
  // min height -1600(underground)
  const minimumHeights = new Array(pointsArray.length / 2).fill(-1600);
  const positions = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(pointsArray);
  const cartographics: Cesium.Cartographic[] = [];
  positions.forEach((p) => {
    cartographics.push(Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(p));
  });
  Cesium.createWorldTerrainAsync().then((terrainProvider) => {
    const promise = Cesium.sampleTerrainMostDetailed(terrainProvider, cartographics);
    promise.then((data) => {
      // Get height by position
      const heights = data.map((d) => d.height);
      const entity3 = new Cesium.Entity({
        id: 'wall',
        name: '动态立体墙',
        wall: {
          positions: positions,
          maximumHeights: heights,
          minimumHeights: minimumHeights,
          material: Cesium.Color.fromCssColorString('rgba(0,255,255)'), // rgba(0,255,255)
          fill: true
        }
      });
      cesiumViewer.value?.entities.add(entity3);
    });
  });
};

I hope the underground wall will be obscured by terrain.

can you share code as Sandcastle?

You need to set depthTestAgainstTerrain = true; in viewer options
https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Globe.html#depthTestAgainstTerrain
then all entities will be not visible thru the ground, but if you need to make them visible back, or show some entities, then you could add disableDepthTestDistance: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY for any entity, which should be visible always.
https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/PointGraphics.html#disableDepthTestDistance
